# How to get DbContext in ABP service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dbcontext, asp.net-boilerplate, abp

How to get `DbContext` instance in application layer?

I tried:

1.

```
public class SeedingTestDataAppService : MyAppServiceBase
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _ctx;

    public SeedingTestDataAppService
    (
        MyDbContext context // Error
    )
    {
        _ctx = context;
    }
}
```

2.

```
public class SeedingTestDataAppService : MyAppServiceBase
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _ctx;

    public SeedingTestDataAppService
    (
        IDbContextProvider<MyDbContext> dbContextProvider
    )
    {
        _ctx = dbContextProvider.GetDbContext();
        // Error: unitOfWork is null
    }
}
```

I am not good at ABP. Where and how can I take a `DbContext` instance and inject it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not call `dbContextProvider.GetDbContext()` in the constructor.

Implement `_ctx` as a getter and use it wherever you actually need the context.

```cs
public class SeedingTestDataAppService : MyAppServiceBase
{
    private MyDbContext _ctx => _dbContextProvider.GetDbContext();
    private readonly IDbContextProvider<MyDbContext> _dbContextProvider;

    public SeedingTestDataAppService(IDbContextProvider<MyDbContext> dbContextProvider)
    {
        _dbContextProvider = dbContextProvider;
    }
}
```