# Connection pooling issue with SQL Server and .NET Core app

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, iis, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET Core 3.1 solution comprising two web apps and two console apps. They all share a single database. However, one of the web apps, named MobileApi, which serves mobile devices, periodically crashes, requiring a restart from IIS.

Upon examining the logs, I've noticed two errors that appear to be related:

> Mvc.ExceptionHandling.AbpExceptionFilter - Timeout expired.  The
> timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.
> This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and
> max pool size was reached. System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout
> expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection
> from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections
> were in use and max pool size was reached.

And the other one is

> Mvc.ExceptionHandling.AbpExceptionFilter - The client has disconnected
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException: The client
> has disconnected  ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
> (0x80070040): The specified network name is no longer available.
> (0x80070040)

I begin to receive hundreds of these errors in the log file, eventually leading to the MobileApi crashing. The MobileApi utilizes two databases: the primary database shared by all applications and another database serving as a queue. Each POST call dumps data into the MobileDb, after which the ConsoleApp reads messages in batches of 1000 and updates the main database.

I am using SQL Server and Entity Framework. The database is deployed on an Azure VM and the application is also deployed on another Azure VM (IIS).

This is how we're registering the database:

```
public static class DbContextConfigurer
{
    public static void Configure(DbContextOptionsBuilder<MobileDbContext> builder, string connectionString)
    {
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }

    public static void Configure(DbContextOptionsBuilder<MobileDbContext> builder, DbConnection connection)
    {
        builder.UseSqlServer(connection, options => {
            options.EnableRetryOnFailure(1);
        });    
    }
}

Configuration.Modules.AbpEfCore().AddDbContext<MobileDbContext>(options =>
{
    if (options.ExistingConnection != null && options.ExistingConnection.ConnectionString == options.ConnectionString)
    {
        DbContextConfigurer.Configure(options.DbContextOptions, options.ExistingConnection);
    }
    else
    {
        DbContextConfigurer.Configure(options.DbContextOptions, options.ConnectionString);
    }
});
```

Both DBCOntext has the same kind of configuration.

The connection string looks like:

```
   "Default": "server=**;database=****;user id=**;password='****';MultipleActiveResultSets=True;",
   "Mobile": "server=**;database=***;user id=**;password='****';MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
```

Do I need to increase Max Pool Size in the connection string? Or should I remove existing connection check from Db configuration.

Comment: Do you have some replication/failover setup in your databases?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the cloud infrastructure being used in pretty cheap.

Comment: Where would the `ExistingConnection` come from, and are you disposing it?

Comment: We're asking EFCore for an existing connection and DI must handle the disposing. I also found this chunk little fishy when I joined. That's why I am asking if it's a good option or not.

Comment: Can you check in logs which queries are executed in this period? Probably something heavy for SQL Server.

Comment: How can I check that if I don't have the SqlProfiler enabled during that time?

Comment: You have EF Core and it's logging.

Comment: I only have log4net enabled for the application logs.

Comment: The question's code has nothing to do with timeouts or pooling. It's just an overcomplicated way of using `builder.Services.AddDbContext`. If DbContext is *misused* though, by creating explicit long lived database transactions, EF Core will have to create a new connection for every new DbContext and keep it open. A DbContext by itself *doesn't* use any connections until it has to either load or save data. Once done, it closes the connection immediately. EF Core won't exhaust the connection pool if used as intended

Comment: If the application starts a database transaction though, or uses TransactionScope around a DbContext, the database connection will have to remain open until the transaction either commits or rolls back. A bad attempt to create a "unit of work" by using explicit transactions will result in connections that remain open *and* keep their locks for the duration of a request instead of just query or save operations.

Comment: I mean I know it's ABP again, But I guess instead of using UnitOfWorkManager.Current.GetDbContext<MobileDbContext>(); I can call IDBCOntextProvider to get the dbcontext (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57772464/how-to-get-dbcontext-in-abp-service)

Comment: We can't guess what your code is doing or how it ended up keeping connections open. Adding more code will only make things worse. I repeat, EF Core doesn't keep connections open. Using `TransactionScope` or `DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction()` *does* keep connections open until the transaction completes. You'll have to find where either of these are used and *remove* it. ABP may be trying to put multiple DbContexts under the same "ambient" transaction by using TransactionScope. Remove or disable that "ambient" transaction

Comment: Do you have anywhere that's invoking `dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection()`? That returns an `IDisposable` `SqlConnection` object which should be protected with a `using`, just like you need to protect any `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` objects you spawn from it.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, no. I don't have that thing in my solution.

Comment: Debug Diagnostics Tool (DebugDiag) can be a lifesaver. It creates and analyze IIS crash dumps. Maybe you can figured out the crash once checking the call stack. But analyzing the dump file is a complex process, so I recommend you to open a support ticket via: https://support.microsoft.com, there will be professional technicians to assist you in grabbing the dump file and analyzing it.