# Disposing DbContext receiveed from UnitOfWorkManager

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I am using .Net Core 3.1 app with aspnet boiler plate template. ABP provides IUnitOfWorkManager. We can either inject IUnitOfWorkManager in the constructor e.g

```
private readonly IUnitOfWorkManager _unitOfWorkManager;
public MyClass(IUnitOfWorkManager unitOfWorkManager
{
  _unitOfWorkManager = unitOfWorkManager
}

public async Task MyMethod()
{
  var context = _unitOfWorkManager.Current.GetDbContext<MyDbContext>();
 ...
}
```

Or we can direcrly ue the UnitOfWorkManager property provided by ABP in the method e.g:

```
 public async Task MyMethod()
    {
      var context = UnitOfWorkManager.Current.GetDbContext<MyDbContext>();
     ...
    }




public IUnitOfWorkManager UnitOfWorkManager
      {
          get
          {
              if (_unitOfWorkManager == null)
              {
                  throw new AbpException("Must set UnitOfWorkManager before use it.");
              }
    
              return _unitOfWorkManager;
          }
          set
          {
              _unitOfWorkManager = value;
          }
      }
```

The question is, do I need to call Dispose() method for disposing the DBContext if I use either of the above mentioned approach? Because I am getting pool starvation exceptions in the logs and one of the most called Api is using the second approach.

Comment: A DbContext *is* a Unit-of-Work, it doesn't need any "managers". You dispose it when you know you want to discard the changes, or, if you use ASP.NET Core, you let the DI container dispose it at the end of a request. You call `SaveChanges` to commit all changes at once. It doesn't matter what ABP does to give the impression of implementing current fads

Comment: Fine, so I need to dispose the dbcontext or will the DI take care of it?

Comment: As all ASP.NET Core tutorials and courses show, you let the DI container dispose it at the end of the request. `AddDContext` registers a DbConetxt as a scoped service by default. In ASP.NET Core (not Blazor), the scope is the request. That means that *unless* you call `SaveChanges` inside a request, all changes are discarded at the end.

Comment: Actually I've explained the complete problem in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78145999/connection-pooling-issue-with-sql-server-and-net-core-app?noredirect=1#comment137769098_78145999). But I also see UnitOfWorkManager.Current.GetDbContext<MobileDbContext>(); inside of many methods. That's why i was unsure if DI is handling it properly or not

Comment: In background services or Blazor, where there's no request, you need to either create your own scope or use a `using` block with newly created DbContexts. That's explained in [Consuming a scoped service in a background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task) and [Blazor with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-8.0). The techniques apply to any scoped service, not just DbContext

Comment: ABP isn't ASP.NET Core. There's no reason to doubt that DI works. ABP on the other hand is known to use a lot of *bad* practices to give the impression of doing "best practices". Anything that puts a "unit-of-work" over DbContext is a huge red flag

Comment: Actually almost all the most called methods (either from a background task or from an Api) has this line UnitOfWorkManager.Current.GetDbContext<MobileDbContext>();

Comment: EF Core has no such class. It doesn't need it at all. I have no idea what that class does, what its lifetime is, or even what `Current` may refer to. Global singletons like `Whatever.Current` are considered a bad design, which is why HttpContext.Current no longer exists in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Yeah, it's ABP. But I can't change it and at the same time struggling to figure out if I should dispose the DbContexts. I don't see any other good reason of pool starvation. The only other thing is that we are first check if existing connection exists then use that else create a new one. So maybe there are some un disposed connections which leads to the pool starvation

Comment: One more question though, do you see any issue by using existing connection in DbContext configuration? I've mentioned the implementation here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78145999/connection-pooling-issue-with-sql-server-and-net-core-app?noredirect=1#comment137769209_78145999)

Comment: Yes - lots of extra classes and methods that offer little but obscure what's going on. Connection pooling is performed by the ADO.NET driver, not EF Core. There's no reason to move `AddDbContext` to a static class and the `.AbpEfCore().AddDbContext` method uses the same code twice. In *both* branches, the connection string is the same. None of this has to do with timeouts though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ABP looks like it's trying to be anything and everything, a "hey we support this cool new feature also"

Comment: @Charlieface the real problem is in the other question, not here. If you check the source of [UnitOfWorkManager](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp/Domain/Uow/UnitOfWorkManager.cs) you'll see it may create DbContexts inside a TransactionScope. It doesn't matter when you dispose it if the ambient TransactionScope is still active. The transaction is still active so the connections are still open. In the other question the connection pool gets exhausted after a while

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Then the `TransactionScope` needs disposing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ABP UnitOfWorkManager, from the documentation and naming convention I would say that No, you would not want to explicitly dispose of the `DbContext` returned by "GetDbContext()". From the limited example code I could find around the ABP framework, the examples do not wrap the `DbContext` instances retrieved with `using()` blocks so I fully expect that it is operating as a service locator, exposing the instance it is using within its UoW/Repository wrapper classes. However, that is without looking at the source code (if available) for the ABP framework. It comes down to whether the manager is acting as a Service Locator or a Factory. A factory pattern would create and return a new instance of a `DbContext`, and this typically, but not always implies that the consumer should be responsible for disposal. (At the very least the factory should expect that the consumer may, or may not dispose of the instance) A Service Locator pattern on the other hand will manage the lifetime scope of the items it holds and provide references to those instances. In these cases you do not want to explicitly dispose of an instance, as that instance is shared between all code requesting that reference.

There is one simple debugging test you can try to determine if the GetDbContext is a factory or service locator method:

```
var context1 = UnitOfWorkManager.Current.GetDbContext<MyDbContext>();
var context2 = UnitOfWorkManager.Current.GetDbContext<MyDbContext>();
bool isSameReference = Object.ReferenceEquals(context1, context2);
```

If "isSameReference" comes back as `true` then you should not dispose of the instance. If it is `false` and the Get method is returning new instances then you most likely should dispose.

Edit: For ABP and it's UnitOfWorkManager, if you have parallel tasks you should be able to leverage the `.Begin()` method to scope a DbContext for the task.  To verify this you can debug the following test code and it should result in different references. You won't need to explicitly dispose of the DbContext in this case, but wrap the UnitOfWork returned by the manager with a `using()` block to dispose it and the contained DbContext:

```
using (var uow1 = UnitOfWorkManager.Begin())
{
    var context1 = uow1.GetDbContext<MyDbContext>();
    using (var uow2 = UnitOfWorkManager.Begin())
    {
         var context2 = uow2.GetDbContext<MyDbContext>();
         bool isSameReference = Object.ReferenceEquals(context1, context2);
    } // uow2 and context2 will be disposed...
} // uow1 and context1 will be disposed...
```

I would fully expect that "isSameReference" would be false in the above case.

If so, then the Task method to be parallelized can be updated to:

```
public async Task MyMethod()
{
    using (uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
    {
         var context = uow.GetDbContext<MyDbContext>();
         ...
    }
}
```

This would allow parallelization and ensure the DbContext instance is disposed.

Comment: So I did the test. If I call the DBContext twice in the same method as you did then it returns the same object back. But if I recall the same method then it creates a new instance of the DbContext. So the scope seems like instance per request.

Comment: Yep, so that unit of work will almost certainly be managing the disposal of the DbContext instance. This does mean though that you cannot count on it if you want to do something like parallelization.

Comment: I do have a background job that calls this bit inside of a parallel loop. Should I change it?

Comment: Yes. DbContext instances are not thread safe so background jobs should be using a DbContextFactory or a new Unit of Work instance scope wrapper to provide new individual instances within the scope of code running in the worker thread. That code would then be responsible for disposing of that DbContext instance. I'm not familiar with ABP but to me I would expect a UnitOfWork "Manager" creating unit of work instances like a factory and possibly defaulting to a common single unit of work instance by default.

Comment: I had a quick peek at the documentation: Have a look at `IUnitOfWorkManager.Begin` within the task, that looks like it should handle a new unit of work instance wrapping a new DbContext instance. (https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Unit-Of-Work)

Comment: Do you prefer to use UnitOfWorkManager.Begin instead of UnitOfWorkManager.Current.GetDbContext ?

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example to check the behaviour, and the resulting task method for parallel background running using Begin to scope a new unit of work. Current.GetDbContext returns a shared instance so you cannot use that for a background worker when there is a risk that the DbContext could be accessed on two or more threads concurrently.

Comment: I guess GetDbContext is only available on IActiveUnitOfWork which is returned by .Current. Begin() returns IUnitOfWorkCompleteHandle which doesn't contain a definition for GetDbContext. Also I guess in the scenario where multiple threads try to access same instance of DbContext, it throws exception. In my case I am facing pool starvation and getting different error. I've mentioned the details in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78145999/connection-pooling-issue-with-sql-server-and-net-core-app?noredirect=1#comment137776361_78145999)